# What is the order of operations for PDE subscripts and superscripted exponents?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation, convention

…that is, if there is convention consensus.

If $u$ is a multivariate function of $x, \ldots$ , does $u^2_x$ mean $(u^2)_x$ or $(u_x)^2$ ?

Comment: It means $(u_x)^2$.

Comment: @KennyWong Thank you! That's an answer; please post it.